# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.register.Model.Cartmodel

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get my app to read data from Firebase Realtime Database. I'm getting this error

> "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.register.Model.Cartmodel"

This is the code where I data is written:

```
    private void addtocart() {
    String saveCurrentDate, saveCurrentTime;
    Calendar calForDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    saveCurrentDate = currentDate.format(calForDate.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");
    saveCurrentTime = currentTime.format(calForDate.getTime());

    final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");
    String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    double price = Double.parseDouble(emailholder.getText().toString().replace("₹", ""));
    double quantityValue = Double.parseDouble(quantity.getText().toString());
    double result = price * quantityValue;

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String purl = intent.getStringExtra("purl");



    final HashMap<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
    cartMap.put("productName",nameholder.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("productPrice",emailholder.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("productImage", purl);
    cartMap.put("date",saveCurrentDate);
    cartMap.put("time",saveCurrentTime);
    cartMap.put("quantity",quantity.getText().toString());
    cartMap.put("totalPrice",result);

    String currentUserPhoneNumber = Paper.book().read(Prevalent.UserPhoneKey);

    cartListRef.child("currentUserPhoneNumber")
            //.child(timestamp)
            .updateChildren(cartMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(details.this, "Added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }
            });



    }
```

this is Model class which is giving error

```
package com.example.register.Model;
```

public class Cartmodel {

```
String date;
String productImage;
static String productName;
String productPrice;
static String quantity;
String time;
static String totalPrice;



public Cartmodel() {
}

public Cartmodel(String date, String productImage, String productName, String quantity, String time, String totalPrice,String productPrice) {
    this.date = date;
    this.productImage = productImage;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.time = time;
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

public String getProductPrice() {
    return productPrice;
}

public void setProductPrice(String productPrice) {
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getProductImage() {
    return productImage;
}

public void setProductImage(String productImage) {
    this.productImage = productImage;
}

public static String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public static String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public static String getTotalPrice() {
    return totalPrice;
}

public void setTotalPrice(String totalPrice) {
    this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
}
```

}

this is the code where im reading data from db

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String currentUserPhoneNumber = Paper.book().read(UserPhoneKey);
    String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cartmodel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cartmodel>()
                    .setQuery(cartListRef.child("currentUserPhoneNumber")
                            /**.child(timestamp)**/,Cartmodel.class).build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cartmodel, CartViewHolder> adapter
            =new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cartmodel, CartViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Cartmodel model) {
            holder.TxtQunatity.setText(Cartmodel.getQuantity());
            holder.TxtProductPrice.setText(Cartmodel.getProductName());
            holder.TxtProductName.setText(Cartmodel.getTotalPrice());
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_row,parent,false);
            CartViewHolder holder = new CartViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

}

this is the database structure of Cart List

```
"Cart List": {
"currentUserPhoneNumber": {
  "date": "Feb 15, 2023",
  "productImage": "https://images.jdmagicbox.com/comp/mumbai/z3/022pxx22.xx22.181204184809.b5z3/catalogue/burger-king-santacruz-east-mumbai-burger-king-3hofjz4vmz.jpg",
  "productName": "Chicken Burger",
  "productPrice": "₹₹350",
  "quantity": "3",
  "time": "15:08:00 PM",
  "totalPrice": 1050
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: hey @AlexMamo I attached the database structure

Comment: So you expect to receive `Cartmodel` objects?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes..

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the following query:

```
cartListRef.child("currentUserPhoneNumber")
```

To the `.setQuery() method`, where `cartListRef` is defined as:

```
DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");
```

It means that you tell the adapter to render `Cartmodel` objects that exist at the above reference. Seeing your database schema, there are no `Cartmodel` objects at that location, but only strings and a number.

So to solve this, you have to remove the call to `.child("currentUserPhoneNumber")` and pass only the `cartListRef` object.

Comment: Hey Aditya. Can I help you with other information regarding this question?